# Can I create CSR for Symantec EV SSL from another machine?

Tags: https, security-certificate

Given the additional checks to validate the organisation for the EV certificates, must the CSRs be created from the actual production web servers?

In my capacity as a contractor, I thought I would use my standard VM with IIS 7.5 and create CSRs with the right details (CN, O, OU, L, S, C), complete the request and export a password-protected PFX file including private key.

The actual production environment has web servers behind a load balancer, so the certificate (PFX) will be imported into each.

Does this approach work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach will work. The information you enter when creating the CSR is all it contains. The resulting certificate can be imported to any certificate store and used for its intended purpose on any software, provided that any tools required to manage the certificate are present.

For Windows Server, use the [MMC Certificate Snap-in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754431.aspx) and choose the computer account. Import the certificate and any intermediate CA certificates, then select the certificate in IIS when enabling SSL for the site.